# HTML input to accept only numbers and letters without scripting

Tags: html

**Input type must accept only:**

- letters(a-z and A-Z)
- Numbers(only positive integers)
- No Special Characters

Comment: Have you searched for `Pattern`?

Comment: @Karthik.Ballary have you googled yet? It seems like you haven't googled or done any research. Try doing research before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this by using the `pattern` attribute which uses regex (regular expressions) to define what can be submitted.

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]+$"></input>
```

**EDIT:** Updated the above to include `^` and `+$` to match the beginning and the end of a line.

I have also built a tested and working example of the above: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aXbybR